# Generate Make Files (for GCC) from Visual Studio Solution

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, gcc, makefile

I want to compile my **Visual Studio Solution**, with three projects, in Linux using GCC. The solution contains two **DLL projects** and **one application(.EXE) project** which uses these DLLs. The source code doesn't contain any Windows dependency.

How do I convert the solution (with 3 projects) to make files which can be compiled in Linux using **GCC**.

Is there is any tool for converting the Visual Studio Solution (Project) to make file/s.

The Visual Studio version is **Visual Studio 2008**

Comment: use [make-it-so](http://code.google.com/p/make-it-so/), also [see answers here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649606/vcxproj-to-cmake).

Comment: Does make-it-so work with VS2013?

Answer (score 6):

Maybe this can help you, but you need to handle whit you outputs in the original code

Make-It-so

http://code.google.com/p/make-it-so/

or 
sln2mak

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28908/Tool-for-Converting-VC-2005-Project-to-Linux-Makef

i hope this can help you

Answer (score 3):

You can use i.e. [vcproj2cmake](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vcproj2cmake/) or [vcxproj2cmake](https://github.com/envi/vcxproj2cmake). Further tools are already listed here:
[How to support both vcxproj to cmake on a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649606/vcxproj-to-cmake/9387350#9387350)

Answer (score -1):

First, Linux don't have DLLs, it has shared objects which can be dynamically linked, with a different semantics. Read Levine's [Linkers & Loaders](http://www.iecc.com/linker/) book for more, and the [Program Library Howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/) and Drepper's [*How to write shared libraries*](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf). For C++, be aware of [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) and see also the [C++ dlopen mini-howto](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/C++-dlopen/index.html).

Then, I think that you should not try to convert your VS project into a `Makefile`, you should code a good `Makefile` by yourself.

Don't forget to setup your `Makefile` so that `-Wall` is passed to GCC (and perhaps also `-std=gnu99`, and `-g` if you want debugging information, probably thru`CFLAGS` or `CXXFLAGS`).

Unless your program is a million line of code application, you won't have much trouble in writing your own `Makefile`. I strongly suggest to learn to use [GNU make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/) and to read its documentation, which seems to me well written (with some tutorial part). You might glance at the output of `make -p` which gives the "builtin knowledge" of GNU `make`.

You could also look inside existing free software Linux applications and study their `Makefile`.

BTW, if you have hard time debugging your makefiles, use [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/).

Don't think in terms of "converting my app to Linux" but more in terms of "coding a Linux app".

Notice that some frameworks (notably Qt) exist to develop software portably to Linux and Windows and MacOS. You might even use them for non-GUI applications.

Don't forget to read material like [advanced linux programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com) and [advanced unix programming](http://basepath.com/aup/)