# Easiest way to "port" a Visual Studio C++ project to compile on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, gcc, makefile

Have been developing a Visual Studio (2012) C++ project and wondered what would be the most convenient way of being able to copy it over to Linux so that I could re-compile the whole project there? Assume the C++ is platform-independent.

Would it be a case of copying all the .h and .cpp files manually in to one folder, copy that folder to Linux and then somehow creating a script (makefile?) which controls how the files are compiled? I'm not too sure if a makefile is what I require- but any mechanism so that I can compile the whole project from one command on the terminal?

Comment: Maybe this question helps http://stackoverflow.com/q/12875013/1741542

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/make-it-so/ for the benefit of everyone else

Answer (score 1):

For the physical part, the easiest solution is to just grab the sources from your Version Control System. That will take care of the `\r\n` -> `\n` translation in your .cpp and .h files.

On the linux side, pretty much any build tool is superior to raw `make`. `make` is really the assembly language of build systems; your tool might produce a `makefile` as an intermediary but don't try to maintain that.

Comment: Depends on the complexity of the build process. If it's just a matter of throwing a compiler at all the .cc files in one go, a makefile might be the simplest approach.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, copy the files (or as @MSalters says - checkout a fresh copy) then construct an alternative .vcxproj for the Linux build tools. Note that the Visual Studio project file is really just a very fancy type of makefile.

A makefile at its simplest is just a list of files (or file types even) and a command for running on them. Once you have that written up, building is as simple as running MSBuild against a .sln file.

So you need to decide which build system to use on Linux - there's CMake which is a makefile-generator, and [several other systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_build_automation_software) available.

[Someone has made a tool](http://code.google.com/p/make-it-so/) that parses the VS project file and can generate a makefile from it, but it doesn't support VS2012 (you can fix this though, contribute)