# Target won't run if Outputs is empty (incremental build)

Tags: msbuild

I have an incremental build setup. When the output files do not exist (e.g. first build) the target does not run since `Outputs="@(MyOutput)"` results in an empty list. To workaround this, I use this:

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'@(MyOutput)' == ''">
   <MyOutput Include="FakeOutputFile.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: Can you add more context? What's the `Target` that runs that depends on the ItemGroup `MyOutput`?

Comment: @Hank see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15450950

Answer (score 0):

MSBuild will always try to map input files to output files in a 1-to-1 manner. If it can't do that, it will make sure that all input files timestamps are older than all the output files.

The best solution if you are just mapping files 1-to-1 is to transform the input files directly into their final output file destination.

Note: 1-to-1 mappings can only be produced by making the `Outputs` attribute a transformation of the `Inputs` attribute. [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/incremental-builds?view=vs-2022).

```xml
<ItemGroup>
 <Headers Include="*.file" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="AfterBild" 
        Inputs="@(Headers)"
        Outputs="@(Headers->'$(OutDir)%(FileName).xml')" >
 <!-- Some exe that transforms each .file into .xml -->
 <Exec ... />
</Target>
```

The `%(FileName)` is just a example of the [well-known item metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-well-known-item-metadata?view=vs-2022).

Sometimes you are only producing one output file, such as a help file then you just compare it to that final output. I have personally used this

```
<ItemGroup>
  <HelpContent Include="$(RepoRoot)\doc\Help\**\*.*" />
</ItemGroup>
<Target Name="BuildHelp" AfterTargets="AfterBuild" Inputs="@(HelpContent)" Outputs="$(OutDir)Help.chm">
    <ItemGroup>
      <SourceFile Include="$(RepoRoot)\doc\Help\Help.chm" />
      <DestinationFile Include="$(OutDir)\Help.chm" />
    </ItemGroup>
  <Exec Command="&quot;$(RepoRoot)\lib\HTML Help Compiler\hhc.exe&quot; &quot;$(RepoRoot)\doc\Help\Help.hhp&quot;" IgnoreExitCode="true" StandardOutputImportance="low" />
  <Move SourceFiles="@(SourceFile)" DestinationFiles="@(DestinationFile)" />
</Target>
```

Leave a comment if you need more specific help since I don't know exactly what your target is unless its the exact Doxygen target you linked.

Comment: In my case, one or more input files produce one output file, so I cannot use the one to one transform.