# Use existing Visual Studio project in cmake

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I have a bunch of cmake generated projects and one which was created under MSVS. I want to have it added whenever I rerun cmake. Now I have to generate solution by cmake and then add existing project to the solution from the MSVS GUI but it is a bit tedious.

Is there a way to automatize the process?

Comment: possible duplicate of [vcxproj to cmake](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649606/vcxproj-to-cmake)

Comment: It is not duplicate. This question is different.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I found a way to do it:

It is as simple as just put the following line in a cmake file: `INCLUDE_EXTERNAL_MSPROJECT(<Name> <Path>)`

I've also had dependencies in my MS project and those dependencies were on the projects generated by the CMake so I had to re-add deps every time I do clean build or change the machine I'm working on. It was solved with manually setting GUID for the CMake generated projects:
`SET(${PROJECT_NAME}_GUID_CMAKE "<GUID>" CACHE INTERNAL "Project GUID")`

So now I can work with projects generated by CMake and "native" MSVS project without any pain.

Comment: If you can or do not want to modify the MakeLists.txt, this can also be specified on the command line: `-D<project-name>_GUID_CMAKE:INTERNAL="<guid>"`  CMake will list this under "Manually-specified variables were not used by the project" but it'll work anyway.

Comment: does it support other generators?

Comment: @Sergei, I have no idea

Comment: I tried this, it does not seem to work:  install TARGETS given target "SomeProject.Packaging.androidproject"
  which is not an executable, library, or module.  include_external_msproject( "SomeProject" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/SomeProject.Packaging/" TYPE "{39E2626F-3545-4960-A6E8-258AD8476CE5}" )