# Compile Visual Studio 2012 project with GCC

Tags: visual-c++, gcc, visual-studio-2012, cross-platform, cross-compiling

I need to compile a C++ project written in VS2012 with GCC. Do I need to rework on the vcxproj file? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you mean use `gcc` and continue targeting Windows (not actually cross-compiling), or do you mean use `gcc` so your program will run on a non-Windows platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to either compile everything by hand or write a Makefile, CMakeLists.txt, bjam, scons, or premake or whatever file to compile your project. It may not take too much time depending on the scope and size of the project, and your familiarity with a decent build system.

Answer (score 0):

See:

[How to support both vcxproj to cmake on a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649606/vcxproj-to-cmake)

There are bunch of tools can convert xproj to a makefile.