# Are there any tools out there to convert vcproj/vcxproj files into standalone CMakeLists?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I've found [vcproj2cmake](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vcproj2cmake/) but it appears to work inline, the cmake projects it generates are reliant on the vcproj and not standalone.

[vcxproj2cmake](https://github.com/envi/vcxproj2cmake) Also seems to be an option, but I cannot get it to work, I am having the same issues as in [issue#8](https://github.com/envi/vcxproj2cmake/issues/8).

Does anyone know of a direct .vc[x]proj -> CMakeList.txt converter?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I find a tool to convert a VS solution to a gcc makefile?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/870533/where-can-i-find-a-tool-to-convert-a-vs-solution-to-a-gcc-makefile)

Comment: That question was specifically asking for conversion to makefiles, not cmake

Comment: Sorry - you're right - I was thinking of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649606/vcxproj-to-cmake)

Comment: I recommend to either write some script by yourself, or port it manually. Autogenerated CMake files tend to be a mess.