# From Visual Studio projects to CMake projects

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I have a bunch of projects setup in Visual Studio 2008. However, from what I've done to maintain my code projects, it is not a good way to.

I've known that those projects would be maintained in a much better way with [CMake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMake) (CMake files) and just the code files (cpp, h).

So... Is there a type of conversion from my Visual Studio project files to CMakeLists.txt and other CMake files neccessary to rebuild my projects?
Or I would have to write the CMakeLists.txt and other files for every project again?

Comment: possible duplicate of [vcxproj to cmake](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649606/vcxproj-to-cmake)

Comment: There are a few tools the link above. I have tried them all and recommend manually converting the projects instead.

Comment: I've just tried the tool vcproj2cmake. since they use direct paths and dispose the CMake modules. I don't think they will help much for build on another computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that there is way of automagically converting between VS and CMake.

IMO you should create one project as a template (possibly with macros to do your common tasks) and then convert the rest of your projects when you have one that is working.

Comment: thanks! for this answer! not much effort to search for such tool will be paid. But I also believe that more upgrades can be done on vcproj2cmake to make it more automatic with the CMakemodules