# How to compile this GitHub Project on Mac? No instructions

Tags: macos, github, ide, installation, arduino-ide

I'm really interested in an Arduino IDE project from GitHub, but since I'm a new programmer i don't have figured out how to compile those source files on my Mac. There is already ported to Mac as it shows on the version 0.6.0.0 changelog but i just does not know how to do it.
Can someone provide instructions for me?
GitHub link:https://github.com/aporto/mariamole

Answer (score 0):

So as I'm sure you've noticed, that project is a vcxproj-- i.e visual studio.  Compiling it on Mac would require some finagling.  I don't have experience myself, but I found this in my queries for you

[How to support both vcxproj to cmake on a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649606/vcxproj-to-cmake)

You're going to want to read up on a lot of resources to try to get a better understanding and maybe form a better google query.  Alternatively the easiest route would just to get your hands on a windows machine to build this

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You have two options: 
1) There's already a cmake project included in the project file. It's used for compiling it at Linux

2) There's also a Qt .pro file, also included in the project files, that you can load at Qt Creator

Comment: Since Linux and Mac follow the same base OS, Can I use the CMake project on the Mac(after adding the required software like QT Serial)?

Comment: Probably yes, because the same CMake file can be used on Windows. But I have no access to an Apple computer to assure that.

Comment: Ok, Gonna try it out.                                                                                  Thank you!