# Compile a C++14 project in VisualStudio with GCC

Tags: gcc, visual-c++, msbuild, c++14

I am going to start a personal project on `C++14`, using Visual Studio Community 2017  as IDE and GitHub as hosting website. I recently discovered [buddy.works](https://buddy.works/), an online CI service that allows support for 5 GitHub projects in the free tier, but only supports `GCC` as C++ compiler. Thus, I am not sure if I'll be able to flawlessly write code in VS and maintain the CI server.

I read [How to support both vcxproj to cmake on a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649606/how-to-support-both-vcxproj-to-cmake-on-a-project) and figured out that this will indeed be a moderate pain to manage. However, the post is 7 years old and maybe some improvements were made in that time. Are you aware of ways to generate VS projects so that they can be compiled with `GCC`? Should I change my IDE of choice while I'm able to, or change CI service?

Thank you.

[Edit] I just saw in VS2017 you can indeed create a CMake project, "platform independent". It's just about finding a way to translate `CMakeLists.txt` files into standard `Makefile`s then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found out it's possible to use CMake based projects since VS2015, but they won't have the smart code recognition features as `msbuild`-based projects do (in other words, when adding a source file it will not be automatically added to the "project files" / CMake files).
I will have to learn how to write CMakeLists.txt files (which are mostly high-level Makefiles as far as I understand).

In the CI environment, I had to use a version of GCC that came with CMake, and launch it with a specific target:

```
mkdir -p cmake-build && cd cmake-build
cmake .. -G"Unix Makefiles"
make
```

This led to a compiled binary in the `cmake-build` directory.