# What is a Linux equivalent of Visual Studio's 'build code in release mode'?

Tags: c++, linux, portability

I want to run a code available on Github, and the running environment is Visual Studio 2017 Community. The code is for Windows, and I want to modify it for Linux/OSX. To run the code we are supposed to 'Build the code in release mode'. I understand that's a Visual Studio feature, what is its equivalent in linux?

Comment: Typically build with optimizations enabled, the `NDEBUG` macro defined, and then [`strip`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strip.1.html) the executable program.

Comment: First migrate your project from Visual Studio solution to `cmake`. `cmake` is a tool which is able to generate project files for many platforms (solutions for MSVC or other build system from other platforms). `'Build the code in release mode` is just a switch in build system which you will use in Linux.

Comment: @MarekR okay, so I looked up SO answer at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649606/how-to-support-both-vcxproj-to-cmake-on-a-project and the idea is to use vcxproj2cmake on a vcxproj2cmake executable? What should be the target file configuration/extension? Is it a txt file? Does it need a specific name? I'm sorry I'm absolutely new to this.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so what I understand is that I need to write a make file which builds the project according to the options you have given. How can I write this make file, I  have never used c++ so some pointers will be very helpful.