# C++ vcxproj and sln on Mac OS

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-2017

I am on university currently and in this semester almost all subjects are related to C++, the problem is that all the resource I am getting are VS projects and solutions and the version of Microsoft Visual Studio for Mac OS does not support C++. To make things even worse we are using couple of different libraries but If I could somehow solve the problem of opening and editing project files I think that importing the libs would be small problem. So, is there any way that I can open and work with that projects and solutions beside Parallels cause I don't have money for that.

Comment: If the code has only been written for Windows there are likely to be more problems than just not being able to open the project files. You could try running Windows visual studio under wine, not sure how well that works though

Comment: Wine doesn't look like a good option https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=892. Virtual box is a free alternative to parallels you'll still need a Windows licence though

Comment: You should only use the source code files and create your own XCode project or compile directly from console using (maybe) GNU's compiler. If it's a large project, it is not an easy task

Answer (score 1):

If the number of source files is small you can create a new XCode project and add them to that project manually. If there are a lot of source files maybe some of the tools discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649606/how-to-support-both-vcxproj-to-cmake-on-a-project) can help to automate at least some parts of the conversion.

You can also try one of the VSCode extensions that can open sln files, like [this one](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fernandoescolar.vscode-solution-explorer) and then setup a [clang workflow](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac).

If the code uses Windows specific APIs or libraries this won't be enough and you will have to somehow get a Windows machine.